File doesnot exits
The Python code is of a quiz app. The code returns an 'filenotfound' error though the file is present in a different directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/pyquize.py", line 78, in <module>
    app = QuizeMain()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/pyquize.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.qm = QuizeManager(QuizeMain.QUIZE_FOLDER)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/quize_management.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._build_quiz_list()
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/quize_management.py", line 27, in _build_quiz_list
    dircontent = os.scandir(self.quizefolder)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'pyquiz/quize_xml_files/SampleQuiz.xml'

When i tested the quize_management.py initially it was working perfectly but now its also showing the file not found error
akash@AKASHs-MacBook-Air quizePproject % python -u "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/quize_management.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/quize_management.py", line 63, in <module>
    qm = QuizeManager("pyquiz/quizers/quizers 16-39-29-621/questions_basics/quize_xml_files")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/HP AKASH/quizePproject/pyquiz/quize_management.py", line 22, in __init__
    raise FileExistsError("The quiz folder does not exist")
FileExistsError: The quiz folder does not exist

The error is not clear to me because the code looks fine to me.
Quize_manager the quize manager class is responsible for managing the quize app it save the data and saves the data.  The quizefolder in init function is initialised in the pyquize directory quizemain class.
import os.path
import os
import datetime
from quiz_perser import QuizePerser


class QuizeManager:
    def __init__(self, quizefolder) :
        #to store the quizefile
        self.quizefolder = quizefolder
        #to store the most recent opend quize
        self.the_quize = None
        #to inisiallize the collection of quizes
        self.quizzes = dict()
        #to store the result of the most recent quize
        self.results = None
        #to store the name of the person
        self.quizetaker = "" 

        #to make sure the quizefolder exits
        if not os.path.exists(self.quizefolder):
            raise FileExistsError("The quiz folder does not exist")
        #to build the quize list
        self._build_quiz_list()
    
    def _build_quiz_list(self):
        dircontent = os.scandir(self.quizefolder)
        #to parse the xml file in the quize folder
        for i,f in enumerate(dircontent):
            if f.is_file():
                parser = QuizePerser()
                self.quizzes[i+1] = parser.Perser_quize(f)


    def list_quizzes(self):
        for k, v in self.quizzes.items():
            print(f"({k}): {v.name}")

    def take_quiz(self, quizid, username):
        self.quizetaker = username
        self.the_quize = self.quizzes[quizid]
        self.results = self.the_quize.take_quiz()
        return self.results
    
    def print_results(self):
        self.the_quize.print_results(self.quizetaker)
            

    def save_results(self):
        n = 0

        current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%y_%m_%d")
        file_name = f"{current_date}.txt"
        while(os.path.exists(file_name)):
            file_name = f"{current_date}-{n}.txt"
            n += 1
        with open(file_name, "w") as f:
            self.the_quize.print_results(self.quizetaker, f)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qm = QuizeManager("pyquiz/quizers/quizers 16-39-29-621/questions_basics/quize_xml_files")
    qm.list_quizzes()

The quizemain class maintains the quize behavior.
from quize_management import QuizeManager

class QuizeMain:
    QUIZE_FOLDER = "pyquiz/quize_xml_files/SampleQuiz.xml"

    def __init__(self):
        self.username = "" 
        self.qm = QuizeManager(QuizeMain.QUIZE_FOLDER)
    def startup(self):
        
        self.greetings()
        self.username = input("what is your name: ")
        print(f"Welcome : {self.username} ")



    def greetings(self):
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("~~~~welcome, to the quize~~~~~~~~")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print()

    def goodbye(self):
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print(f"Thank you for taking the quiz : {self.username}")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print()
    
    def menu_header(self):
        print("Plese seclect a option")
        print("M: Repeat this meanu")
        print("L: list the quizes")
        print("T: Take the Quize")
        print("E: exit the program")
        print()

    def menu_error(self):
        print("Your input is invalid, plese try again")
    
    def meanu(self):
        self.menu_header()
        _response = ""
        while (True):
            _response = input("enter your choice : ")
            _response = _response.capitalize()
            if _response[0] == 'E':
                self.goodbye()
                break
            elif _response[0] == 'M':
                self.menu_header()
                continue
            elif _response[0] == 'L':
                print("______________________________")
                self.qm.list_quizzes()
                print("______________________________")
                continue
            elif _response[0] == 'T':
                try:
                    quiznum = int(input("Enter the number of quize"))
                    
                    self.qm.take_quiz(quiznum, self.username)
                    self.qm.print_results()

                except:
                    self.menu_error()

            else:
                self.menu_error()

    def run(self):
        self.startup()
        self.meanu()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QuizeMain()
    app.run()


The quize directory responsible for identifying the question type true/false of multi choice and displays the result and greetings
import datetime

class QuizeApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.correct_count = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.total_points = 0
        self.questions = []

    def take_quiz(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.correct_count = 0
        for q in self.questions:
            q.is_correct = False

        print("------------------")

        for q in self.questions:
            q.ask()
            if(q.is_correct):
                self.score += q.points
                self.correct_count += 1

        return(self.score,self.correct_count,self.total_points)


    def print_results(self, quizetaker):
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print(f"Result for: {quizetaker} ")
        print(f"Date: {datetime.datetime.today()}")
        print(f"Questions: {self.questions}")
        print(f"Correst Questiom: {self.correct_count} out of {len(self.questions)} correctr")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

    def greetings(self):
        print("`````````````````````")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("~~This is a sample questions~~")
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print()
    


    def MenuError(self):
        print("You have not ented any choice")
        print()


class Questions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.correct_answer = " "
        self.is_correct = False
        self.points = 0
        self.text =" "

class QuestionsTF(Questions):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def ask(self):
        while (True):
            print(f"T: True or F: False {self.text} ")
            _Answer = input("?")
            
            if len(_Answer) == 0:
                print("sorry its not a valid answer ")
                continue
            
            _Answer = _Answer.lower()
            if (_Answer[0] != "t" and _Answer[0] != "f"):
                print ("Invalid Input :")
                print(f"T: True or F: False {self.text} ")
                continue

            if _Answer[0] == self.correct_answer:
                self.is_correct = True
            break


class QuestionsMulti(Questions):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.answers = []


    def ask(self):
        while (True):
            print(self.text)
            for a in self.answers:
               print(f"({a.name} {a.text})")

            _Answer = input("?")

            if len(_Answer) == 0:
                print("sorry its not a valid answer ")
                continue
            
            _Answer = _Answer.lower()
            if _Answer[0] == self.correct_answer:
                self.is_correct = True
            break

class Answer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ""
        self.name = ""

The QuizParser class loads a particular quiz file, parses it, and returns
a fully-built Quiz object that can then be presented to the user.
import xml.sax
from quize import *
from enum import Enum, unique

# unique function used to find the unique function in an arry or list and return the unique elements only

@unique
class QuizePerserState(Enum):
    IDLE = 0
    PARSE_QUIZ = 1
    PARSE_DESCRIPTION = 2
    PARSE_QUESTION = 3
    PARSE_QUEST_TEXT = 4
    PARSE_ANSWER = 5

class QuizePerser(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self) :
        self.new_quize = QuizeApp()
        self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.IDLE
        self._current_question = None
        self._current_answer = None

    def Perser_quize(self, quizepath):
        quizetext = ""
        with open(quizepath, "r", encoding="latin-1") as quizefile:  # Or try another encoding like "windows-1252"
            if quizefile.mode == "r":
                quizetext = quizefile.read()

        xml.sax.parseString(quizetext, self)

        return self.new_quize

    def startElement(self, tagname, attrs ):
        if tagname == "QuizML":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUIZ
            self.new_quize.name = attrs["name"]
        elif tagname == "Description" :
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_DESCRIPTION
        elif tagname == "Question":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUESTION
            if (attrs["type"] == "multichoice"):
                self._current_question = QuestionsMulti()
            if (attrs["type"] == "tf"):
                self._current_question = QuestionsTF()
            self._current_question.points = int(attrs["points"])
            self.new_quize.total_points += self._current_question.points
        elif tagname == "QuestionText":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUEST_TEXT
            self._current_question.correct_answer = attrs["answer"]
        elif tagname == "Answer":
            self._current_answer = Answer()
            self._current_answer.name = attrs["name"]
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_ANSWER


    def endElement(self, tagname):
        if tagname == "QuizML":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.IDLE

        elif tagname == "Discription":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUIZ

        elif tagname == "Question":
            self.new_quize.questions.append(self._current_question)
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUIZ
        elif tagname =="QuestionText":
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUESTION
        elif tagname == "Answer":
            self._current_question.answers.append(self._current_answer)
            self._perser_state = QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUESTION

    def characters(self, chars):
        if self._perser_state == QuizePerserState.PARSE_DESCRIPTION:
            self.new_quize.description += chars
        elif self._perser_state == QuizePerserState.PARSE_QUEST_TEXT:
            self._current_question.text += chars
        elif self._perser_state == QuizePerserState.PARSE_ANSWER:
            self._current_answer.text += chars

    
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app = QuizePerser()
#     qz = app.Perser_quize("pyquiz/quizers/quizers 16-39-29-621/questions_basics/quizers_xml_files/SampleQuiz.xml")
#     print(qz.name)
#     print(qz.description)
#     print(len(qz.questions))
#     print(qz.total_points)
#     for q in qz.questions:
#         print(f"Question: {q.text}")
        


The code is trying to call os.scandir() with the argument "pyquiz/quize_xml_files/SampleQuiz.xml", but that is a file, not a directory.

The NotADirectoryError hints that you're passing a filename to a function that expects a directory name.
QUIZE_FOLDER = "pyquiz/quize_xml_files/SampleQuiz.xml"

looks an awful lot like a file name, not a directory name.
Maybe you meant
QUIZE_FOLDER = "pyquiz/quize_xml_files"

there?
As an aside, raise FileExistsError("The quiz folder does not exist") seems a bit strange – shouldn't that be raise FileNotFoundError(...)?

I have changed the code but doesn't work
